# Retornar registo de cada consulta conforme clico no botão

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho 3 registo de consulta numa tabela da base de dados do mesmo utente.

Quando faço consulta retorna e mostra a consulta mais recente da tabela da base de dados.
Eu pretendo retornar as 3 consultas, mostrar sempre a consulta mais recente, mas ter um botão que ao clicar feche a consulta que está a mostrar e abra a consulta anterior e assim sucessivamente até não ter mais consultas. Desta forma tenho sempre acesso à informação registada em cada consulta sobre o utente.

Neste momento retorno a consulta da seguinte maneira:

```
<a name="view2" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal1" class="btn btn-primary view_data2" />EGA</a>

<div id="dataModal1" class="modal fade" style="width:1000px;">  
      <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1000px;">  
           <div class="modal-content" style="width:1000px;">  
                <div class="modal-header" style="width:1000px;">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button> 
                     <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Estado Geral e Autonomia</strong></h4>  
                </div> 
                <div class="container"></div>       
                <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail1">  
                </div> 
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Sair</a>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div> 

$(document).on('click', '.view_data2', function(){  
           var employee_id1 = $(this).attr("Id");  
           if(employee_id1 != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"./select2",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{employee_id1:employee_id1},  
                     success:function(data){  
                     console.log(data);
                          $('#employee_detail1').html(data);  
                          $('#dataModal1').modal('show');  
                     }  
                });  
           } 
         });
```

na página `select2` tenho o seguinte código:

```
if(isset($_POST["employee_id1"]))  
 { 
$output = '';  

$query = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.PsicUtentes WHERE centrodb.PsicUtentes.Id = '".$_POST["employee_id1"]."'"; 
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
      $output;  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {
      $output .= '

                    <h4 class="modal-title">Identificação do Utente</h4>  
                    <form method="post" id="insert_form2">
                        <fieldset class="grupo">
                        <table class="campo" cellspacing="10">
                         <tr>
                          <td>                      
                          <label>Data</label>  
                          <input type="text" id="Data1" name="Data" class="form-control" value="'.$row["Data"].'" style="width:150px;" />  
                          </td> 
                          <td>                      
                          <label>Código Utente</label>  
                          <input type="number" id="CodigoUtente1" name="CodigoUtente" value="'.$row["CodigoUtente"].'" class="form-control" style="width:100px;"/>  
                          </td>
                          <td>                        
                          <label>Nome Utente</label>  
                          <input type="text" id="Nome1" name="Nome" value="'.$row["Nome"].'" class="form-control" class="form-control" style="width:400px;"/>   
                          </td>
                          <td>  
                          <label>Data Nascimento</label>  
                          <input type="date" id="DataNasc1" name="DataNasc" value="'.$row["DataNasc"].'" class="form-control" style="width:150px;"/>   
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        </fieldset>   
                        </form>                  
           ';  
      }  
      $output;  
      echo $output;  
 }
```

Vou mostrar na imagem com fica a página quando tenho três consultas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu pretendia ter um botão como o rodeado a vermelho e sempre que clicasse fechasse a informação da consulta que está a mostrar e abrisse a consulta anterior.

**Tenho esta solução:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('.conteudo').hide(); 

$('.exibir').each(function(i){ 
$(this).click(function(){ 
$('.conteudo').each(function(j){ 
if(i == j) $(this).show('slow'); 
}); 
}); 
}); 
$('.ocultar').each(function(i){ 
$(this).click(function(){ 
$('.conteudo').each(function(j){ 
if(i == j) $(this).hide('slow'); 
}); 
}); 
}); 
}); 
</script> 

if(isset($_POST["employee_id1"]))  
 { 
$output = '';  

$query = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.PsicUtentes WHERE centrodb.PsicUtentes.Id = '".$_POST["employee_id1"]."'"; 
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
      $output;  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {
      $output .= '

                <h4 class="modal-title">Identificação do Utente</h4>
<div> 
<a class="exibir" href="#">Ver</a>-- 
<a href="#" class="ocultar">Ocultar</a>
</div> 

<div class="conteudo"> 
<form method="post" id="insert_form2">
                        <fieldset class="grupo">
                        <table class="campo" cellspacing="10">
                         <tr>
                          <td>                      
                          <label>Data</label>  
                          <input type="text" id="Data1" name="Data" class="form-control" value="'.$row["Data"].'" style="width:150px;" />  
                          </td> 
                          <td>                      
                          <label>Código Utente</label>  
                          <input type="number" id="CodigoUtente1" name="CodigoUtente" value="'.$row["CodigoUtente"].'" class="form-control" style="width:100px;"/>  
                          </td>
                          <td>                        
                          <label>Nome Utente</label>  
                          <input type="text" id="Nome1" name="Nome" value="'.$row["Nome"].'" class="form-control" class="form-control" style="width:400px;"/>   
                          </td>
                          <td>  
                          <label>Data Nascimento</label>  
                          <input type="date" id="DataNasc1" name="DataNasc" value="'.$row["DataNasc"].'" class="form-control" style="width:150px;"/>   
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        </fieldset>   
                        </form>    

<div>
';  
      }  
      $output;  
      echo $output;  
 }
```

Assim funciona, mas ainda queria melhorar uma coisa. Faço ver o primeiro registo, mas quando vejo o segundo o primeiro fica sempre aberto e devia ocultar quando abro o segundo. Já o segundo registo abre quando clico em ver e oculta quando clico em ocultar.

O botão de Editar e Novo devia de aparecer sempre no inicio de abertura de cada div e editar de acordo com a div que abre

Comment: Você poderia criar um contador no click do botão e diminuir do seu Id para buscar o anterior. Ex: Id = 30, clicou uma vez, Id = 30 - 1(contador) e assim sucessivamente

Comment: @Danielle Arruda torres pode colocar um exemplo?

Comment: Sim vou publicar na resposta.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var i = 0;
 $('#incrementa').click(function(){ 
       
    if (i < 20 ) { 
            i++;
        } else if (i = i++) {
            i = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = i;
 })

 $('#decrementa').click(function(){ 
 
  if (i > 0) {--i;} 
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = i;
 })
 
 //basta agora você pegar o contador e diminuir no seu ID
```

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="texto">
    <label id="display">0</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group-buttons">
    <a class="button-link" id="incrementa" href="#">Aumenta</a>
    <a class="button-link" id="decrementa" href="#">Diminuir</a>
  </div>
 
</body>
```

> Id = Id - i , para anterior
>
> Id = Id + i , para próximo

$.ajax({
                         url:"./select2",
                         method:"POST",
                         data:{employee_id1: Id },
                         success:function(data){
                         console.log(data);
                              $('#employee_detail1').html(data);
                              $('#dataModal1').modal('show');
                         }
                    });

Comment: agradeço a ajuda, mas não consegui implentar. Neste momento tenho um problema, é que o botão editar que aparece sempre que abro uma DIV nova, assume sempre a informação do primeiro registo retornado.

Comment: Você precisa atualizar o valor dele sempre que fizer uma consulta, no sucess do .Ajax . 
ex:     success:function(data){  
             $("#NovoValorBotao").val(data.Id);
ou   $("#NovoValorBotao").val(Id); //do contador
}

Comment: pode ajudar nesta pergunta [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/362415/atribuir-duas-chaves-prim%C3%A1rias-num-button)